# A declarative way of reshaping / joining / flattening data in nested maps

Tags: clojure

I'm looking for a nice declarative way of doing the data transformation below in Clojure. I'm perfectly okay to leverage any of the data transformation libraries out there, but would appreciate recommendations. I've looked into Meander, Tracks, DataScript and others but could not find the best fit yet.
Vanilla Clojure gets pretty ugly as the complexity/nesting of the input data grows, and becomes pretty imperativeish.

```
;; my input data
(def db {:items  [{:id 1 :labels [1 2 3]}
                  {:id 2 :labels [2]}
                  {:id 3 :labels []}
                  {:id 4 :labels nil}
                  {:id 5 }]
         :labels [{:id 1 :name "one"}
                  {:id 2 :name "two"}
                  {:id 3 :name "three"}
                  {:id 4 :name "four"}]})

;; what to do here
(defn flatten-labels [d]
  ???)

;; so that I get this
(flatten-labels db)
;; =>
;; {:items
;; [{:id 1 :labels ["one" "two" "three"]}
;;  {:id 2 :labels ["two"]}
;;  {:id 3 :labels []}
;;  {:id 4 :labels []}
;;  {:id 5 :labels []}]}
```

**EDIT:**

```
(defn flatten-labels [{:keys [items labels]}]
  (let [->indexed-maps-by (fn [v idx]
                            (into {} (map #(hash-map (get % idx) %)) v))
        label-db          (->indexed-maps-by labels :id)
        label-lookup      (fn [lid] (get-in label-db [lid :name]))
        ]
    (map #(update % :labels (fn [lids] (mapv label-lookup lids))) items)
    )
  )
```

Here's my vanilla solution, for reference.
Pretty much, I'm constructing a 'lookup table' in the right shape and then (map ... (update ... (map ...))) to transform the nested sequence's elements.

My main concern is this being a bit too step-by-step imperative thingy, and if I could just express the same shaping/transformation in a declarative way, that would hopefully make it way more prone to changes and easier to generalise to more complex datasets with all kinds of this "resolve something by some key somewhere and pull it in here" situations.

Thanks for all recommendations so far, highly appreciated!

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: I have a working vanilla Clojure solution, but I'm not happy with it, that's why I've left the question open for recommendations instead. I'd like to see how others would approach this problem. I'm looking for something as declarative as possible.

Comment: Please add the code you already have to the question and what bothers you about it.

Comment: @cfrick, added my code above - thanks for looking into it! I hope my description of the concerns make sense.

Answer (score 0):

something like this could be helpful:

```
(let [labels (->> db :labels (map (juxt :id :name)) (into {}))
      relabel (fn [item] (update item :labels (partial mapv labels)))]
  (update db :items (partial mapv relabel)))
```

though it's not generic enough, still it solves the task.

more generic variant is to use [specter](https://github.com/redplanetlabs/specter):

```
(require '[com.rpl.specter :as s])

(let [labels (->> db :labels (map (juxt :id :name)) (into {}))]
  (s/replace-in [:items s/ALL :labels s/ALL]
                (comp vector labels)
                db))
```

Comment: Thanks @leetwinski! My vanilla solution is substantially the same idea as yours, cool. As for specter: I've been looking into it a bit, and maybe that is that right way to go. I'll play around with that approach for more complex data with the same underlying "lookup tasks" to see how it scales.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are specifically asking for something *declarative*, you could try to shoehorn [spec](https://clojure.org/guides/spec) into doing what you want. But the definition of the spec would depend on the input data, that is the value at the `:labels` key. I wouldn't say that this is a good way of solving it, but it is arguably quite *declarative* if that is what you are looking for. You need a dynamic var, `label-data`, to make this approach work and a custom conformer, `index-to-label`. The rest is just a regular spec of your database. Something like this:

```
(require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as spec])

(def ^:dynamic label-data {0 "test"})

(defn index-to-label [index]
  (get label-data index ::spec/invalid))

(spec/def ::labels (spec/nilable (spec/coll-of (spec/conformer index-to-label))))
(spec/def ::id number?)
(spec/def ::items (spec/coll-of (spec/keys :req-un [::id] :opt-un [::labels])))
(spec/def ::db (spec/keys :req-un [::items]))

(defn flatten-labels [db]
  (binding [label-data (into {} (for [x (:labels db)] [(:id x) (:name x)]))]
    (spec/conform ::db db)))
```

This is what we get when we try it on your data:

```
(flatten-labels db)
;; => {:items [{:id 1, :labels ["one" "two" "three"]} {:id 2, :labels ["two"]} {:id 3, :labels []} {:id 4, :labels nil} {:id 5}], :labels [{:id 1, :name "one"} {:id 2, :name "two"} {:id 3, :name "three"} {:id 4, :name "four"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rulle, nice approach! I'm all in for the "declaratively describe the shapes, and leverage spec conforming for interpretation. Only thing that doesn't fit my mental model easily is the separate construction of the lookup table - I'd prefer to have the way of getting that data somehow embedded into the data declaration (like a "foreign key" thing?). I hope this makes sense. I'm not actually sure that a perfectly "good" solution exists, that's why I'm trying to leech the brain of some great people out here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

#### helper functions

```
(defn fuse-maps [maps]
  (apply #'merge maps))

(defn pack-map [m key-label value-label]
  (map (fn [[k v]] (into {} {key-label k value-label v})) m))

(defn unpack-map [m key-label value-label]
  (fuse-maps (map (fn [inner-m] (into {} {(key-label inner-m) (value-label inner-m)})) m)))

(defn split-map [m]
  "Each key value pair as separate map"
  (map (fn [[k v]] {k v}) m))

(defn split-pack-map [m key-label value-label]
  "Each key value pair as spearate map in packed manner."
  (flatten (map #(pack-map % key-label value-label) (split-map m))))

(defn list-translate [m l] (map #(get m %) l))

(defn vec-translate [m v] (vec (list-translate m v)))

(defn map-values-translate [m tm]
  (fuse-maps (map (fn [[k v]] {k (vec-translate tm v)}) m)))
```

#### solution function

```
(defn flatten-labels [db]
  (let [labels-db (unpack-map (:labels db) :id :name)
        items-db (unpack-map (:items db) :id :labels)
        result-db (split-pack-map (map-values-translate items-db labels-db) :id :labels)]
  {:items (vec result-db)}))
```

#### try it out

```
(def db {:items  [{:id 1 :labels [1 2 3]}
                  {:id 2 :labels [2]}
                  {:id 3 :labels []}
                  {:id 4 :labels nil}
                  {:id 5 }]
         :labels [{:id 1 :name "one"}
                  {:id 2 :name "two"}
                  {:id 3 :name "three"}
                  {:id 4 :name "four"}]})

(flatten-labels db)
;; {:items [{:id 1, :labels ["one" "two" "three"]}
;;          {:id 2, :labels ["two"]} 
;;          {:id 3, :labels []} 
;;          {:id 4, :labels []} 
;;          {:id 5, :labels []}]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution - it does work, but it's not declarative. What I'm looking to have is a tool to combine the original data, with another piece of data that describes the transformation itself, and come up with the new, expected shape. The functions you've defined are the exact right pieces that need to be combined for the transformation - I'm pretty much looking for something that has the expressive power to describe these manipulations as data, not functions.

Comment: @GáborVeres Yeah I was programming in functional style. I have feeling I don't know what you exactly mean with declarative. How the function call should be so that you would say it is declarative?

Comment: @GáborVeres I mean however your `flatten-labels` function is, you have somewhere to give the information that the keys for the one map are `:id` and `:name` while for the other `:id` and `:labels` and that the final keys must be named `:id` and `:labels`. If you look at only my definition of `flatten-labels` - isn't this declarative enough? You can clearly see where these labels are given as info in the function. The helper functions I had to define because - coming from common lisp - the other answers were for my brain not "logical".

Comment: I think the map keys can be automatically determined only if we have more information e.g. that the input maps will be always of that form etc.

Comment: thanks for sharing the thoughts, it's really valuable! As for what I mean by declarative - fair question. I've been playing around with some great tools such as the Datomic Pull syntax, the Datalog query syntax, Fulcro/Phatom's EQL, Meander Epsilon's matching and rewrite DSLs, and all of these do a great job on combining data with data to come up with a transformation of your input. But, they either do this backed with a database, or target transformations that don't easily fit this exercise. What I wanted to see is whether there is something similar out there that I missed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `clojure.set :as set`

```clj
(let [db {:items  [{:id 1 :labels [1 2 3]}
                   {:id 2 :labels [2]}
                   {:id 3 :labels []}
                   {:id 4 :labels nil}
                   {:id 5}]
          :labels [{:id 1 :name "one"}
                   {:id 2 :name "two"}
                   {:id 3 :name "three"}
                   {:id 4 :name "four"}]}]
  (set/join
    (-> db :items set)
    (-> db :labels set)
    {:id :id}))
=>
#{{:id 4, :name "four", :labels nil}
  {:id 3, :name "three", :labels []}
  {:id 1, :name "one", :labels [1 2 3]}
  {:id 2, :name "two", :labels [2]}}
```

Another one, using only `clojure.core`

```clj
(let [db {:items  [{:id 1 :labels [1 2 3]}
                   {:id 2 :labels [2]}
                   {:id 3 :labels []}
                   {:id 4 :labels nil}
                   {:id 5}]
          :labels [{:id 1 :name "one"}
                   {:id 2 :name "two"}
                   {:id 3 :name "three"}
                   {:id 4 :name "four"}]}]
  (reduce (fn [idx {:keys [id] :as value}]
            (update idx id merge value))
          {}
          ;;(concat (:items db) (:items db))
          (mapcat val db)))
 
=>
{1 {:id 1, :labels [1 2 3], :name "one"},
 2 {:id 2, :labels [2], :name "two"},
 3 {:id 3, :labels [], :name "three"},
 4 {:id 4, :labels nil, :name "four"},
 5 {:id 5}}
```

Just a comment, i think that you should use `{:table-name {idx {:key :value}}}` format, as `fulcro` use.

Comment: thanks, but you're solving a different problem. My intention is to "resolve" the ids in the :labels vectors to their string names using a "join"-like operation. You on the other hand resolve the :id's of the :items with the join.